# Springboot reactive webflux with oauth2 client credentials flow for azure active directory

Tags: spring-security, azure-active-directory, spring-webflux, azure-oauth

I'm trying to get the springboot webflux oauth2 client_credentials flow work but the application is working as expected.

Referring to a lot of questions and answers on stackoverflow, springboot docs I could not get a working solution. Any leads will be appreciated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/ - focusing point [28.4 and 28.3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/#webclient-explicit)

Springboot version : 2.6.5 and so all the starters are of 2.6.5 as well.

I want to pass the clientRegistrationId so that I can use multiple ids as part of request.

If I do not use the CommonConfig class, the app is not starting with an error. But all the examples over internet says springboot auto configures it.

```
a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager' that could not be found.
```

If I use the CommonConfig class assuming the client registration will work, I face the exception mentioned below.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.5</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <spring.boot.version>2.6.5</spring.boot.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <revision>1.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <sonar.coverage.exclusions>
        </sonar.coverage.exclusions>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
                    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>flatten</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>flatten</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>flatten.clean</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

BaseClient:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFilterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class BaseClient {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("defaultWebClient")
    public WebClient defaultWebClient() {
        return WebClient.builder().defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).build();
    }
}
```

TestClient:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.Exceptions;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.util.retry.Retry;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class TestClient {

    @Qualifier("defaultWebClient")
    private final WebClient webClient;

    public Mono<Object> process() {

        Mono<Object> x = webClient.method(HttpMethod.POST).uri("https://some.valid.url.which.is.protected").headers(getBasicHeader()).attributes(
            ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction
                    .clientRegistrationId("testregistrationid")).exchangeToMono(clientResponse);

        x.subscribe(r-> {
            log.info(r.toString());
        });

        return x;
    }

    private static Consumer<HttpHeaders> getBasicHeader() {
        return httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    }
}
```

application.yaml:

```
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: reactive
  profiles:
    active: local
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          testregistrationid:
            client-id: valid-client-id
            client-secret: valid-secret
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            client-authentication-method: post
            provider: testregistrationid
        provider:
          testregistrationid:
            token-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/b7xxxxx0-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/token
  webflux:
    base-path: /test
```

CommonConfig class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
public class CommonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            final ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            final ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {
        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
                ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder().clientCredentials().build();
        DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                new DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository,
                                                                 authorizedClientRepository);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
        return authorizedClientManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.oauth2Client(withDefaults()).build();
    }
}
```

Error-scenario-1:

```
2023-07-07 13:28:38.863 ERROR 75783 --- [] reactor.core.publisher.Operators         : Operator called default onErrorDropped

reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: serverWebExchange cannot be null
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: serverWebExchange cannot be null
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.lambda$authorize$4(DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.java:153)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST https://some.valid.url.which.is.protected [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.lambda$authorize$4(DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.java:153)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:55)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:85)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:150)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilterFuseable.java:171)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2400)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:191)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:169)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2194)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2068)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:87)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCurrentContext.subscribe(MonoCurrentContext.java:36)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:251)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:336)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:109)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:85)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:150)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilterFuseable.java:171)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2400)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:191)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:169)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2194)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2068)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:87)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCurrentContext.subscribe(MonoCurrentContext.java:36)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:128)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4515)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4371)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4307)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4254)
        at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:160)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.onNext(FluxUsingWhen.java:345)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsing$UsingFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxUsing.java:353)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drainAsync(FluxFlattenIterable.java:421)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drain(FluxFlattenIterable.java:686)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFlattenIterable.java:250)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.runBackfused(FluxPublishOn.java:484)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(FluxPublishOn.java:521)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorTrackedRunnable.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:189)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.ImmediateScheduler$ImmediateSchedulerWorker.schedule(ImmediateScheduler.java:84)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SingleWorkerScheduler.execute(SingleWorkerScheduler.java:64)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorSchedulerWorker.schedule(ExecutorScheduler.java:242)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.trySchedule(FluxPublishOn.java:312)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.onNext(FluxPublishOn.java:237)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210)
        at reactor.core.publisher.UnicastProcessor.drainRegular(UnicastProcessor.java:388)
        at reactor.core.publisher.UnicastProcessor.drain(UnicastProcessor.java:470)
        at reactor.core.publisher.UnicastProcessor.tryEmitNext(UnicastProcessor.java:338)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:100)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27)
        at reactor.kafka.receiver.internals.ConsumerEventLoop$PollEvent.run(ConsumerEventLoop.java:371)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: either you configure the oauth client using yaml, or you set it up using the builder pattern. You dont mix and match them both. It is well documented here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/reactive/oauth2/login/core.html#webflux-oauth2-login-custom-provider-properties and you are missing configuration for instance you have not configured the token endpoint where the code is exchanged for a token for instance. And you have not disclosed if this is using `Open ID Connect`

Comment: @Toerktumlare I am using azure https://login.microsoftonline.com/b7xxxxx0-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/token, will update the question as well.

I've provided the token endpoint to generate the token - it is provided as part of yaml file in the question under `provider:registration-id:token-uri`

When you say builder pattern - are you referring to `webClient`, or `CommonConfiguration` class?

Comment: im referring to the `CommonConfiguration` what your `TestClient` is used for i have no idea, its only strange. You are clearly not following the documentation, at all.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I am not sure if you completely read the issue. I mentioned what is the error if `CommonConfiguration` class is not provided.

Also, the `TestClient` is the class which actually makes a call to a protected end point using the provided `webClient` and the `registrationid`. 

I followed a lot of ways (provided by springboot and secuity api docs) and also other examples provided by other websites and most of them suggest to provide the `CommonConfiguration` class as the auto config from yaml files is not working at times.

Comment: @Toerktumlare TO give more info I followed the below link https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/ and more focusing on 28.3 and 28.4 in the page. I all those cases, the primary issue is the registered client not available when followed the documentation